# matlab more efficient random links creation

Tags: matlab, random, graph, matrix

I have this section to make some random links in groups. Can I make it more efficient? Any idea?

Thanks.

```
n=[10 ;10 ;10];
no_of_groups=size(n,1);
for k=1:no_of_groups
    if k==1
        m{k,1}=randi(n(1), n(1),2);%random links between nodes of group1
        m1=rand(n(1),1)/2+0.5;%random weight to edges
        c{k,1} = cat(2,m{1},m1);
    else
        m{k,1}=randi([((k-1)*n(k-1)+1) (k*n(k))],n(k),2););%random links between nodes of group k
        m1=rand(n(k),1)/2+0.5;
        c{k,1} = cat(2,m{k,1},m1);
    end
end
c=cat(1,c{:});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix is to **preallocate** `m` and `c` and **initiliaze** them outside of the loop in order to remove the if condition:

```
n  = [10 ;10 ;10];
no = size(n,1);

% Preallocate
m = cell(no,1);
c = cell(no,1);

% Initialize m and c
m{1} = randi(n(1), n(1),2);%random links between nodes of group1
m1   = rand(n(1),1)/2+0.5;%random weight to edges
c{1} = cat(2,m{1},m1);

for k = 2:no
        m{k} = randi([(k-1)*n(k-1)+1 k*n(k)],n(k),2);%random links between nodes of group k
        m1   = rand(n(k),1)/2+0.5;
        c{k} = cat(2,m{k,1},m1);
end
c=cat(1,c{:});
```

This loop is vectorizable or at least you can avoid using cells, which should boost speed a little bit more.